# What does "dot-bomb" mean?

Tags: word-choice

On The New York Times I read the following sentence:

> The bad news here begins with the economy, which stinks. This is the
>   epicenter of the *dot-bomb*, the edge of the ailing Pacific Rim and
>   now a major casualty of tourist malaise.

What does *dot-bomb* mean?

Answer (score 5):

It's referring to the economic collapse of the "dot-com" boom, which occurred in the late 1990s.  [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-com_bubble) explains it rather well.

Comment: I don't remember dot-bomb at the time, I think dot-bomb is a newer usage.

Comment: I think you're right - but I think it's pretty evident that's what "dot-bomb" is referring to.

Answer (score 5):

It generally means that the new dot-com economy will collapse.
 ie "bomb" in AE=to fail spectacularly.

dot-com + bomb -> dot-bomb

Comment: I believe the author is referring to three consecutive hits causing economic turmoil in California - the dot-com bubble collapse being the first, and a decline in tourism being the most recent.

Comment: @JR - yes, I was reading the second sentence on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too many authoritative references, but I'd say that in this case it's probably a synecdoche, putting *dot-bomb*, a failed dot-com, for the *dot-com bust*, when a bunch of dot-coms failed.

> - NOAD and Oxford Dictionaries Online: `informal` an unsuccessful dot-com [ODO dot-com company]: : *many promising Internet start-ups ended up as dot-bombs.*
> - Wikipedia: With the stock market crash around the year 2000 that ended the dot-com bubble, many failed and failing dot-com companies were referred to punningly as **dot-bombs**, **dot-cons** or **dot-gones**.
> - Wiktionary: A failed dot-com company or venture
> - Urban Dictionary: What happens after thousands of investors in internet companies all forget the hard-learned lessons in software development process and basic business plans: built it well and be profitable. *I lost my job in the dot bomb.*